# is there any way to filter in syslog (not rsyslog) such as programname?

Tags: linux, selinux, rsyslog, syslogd

I need to add filter in my syslogs. I know how to do in rsyslogs. But we need to add same logs in syslogs as well in legacy systems.Is there any way to do it?

Corresponding rsyslog entries are:

```
:msg, contains, "ABC" /var/log/abc.log
:programname, isequal, "sudo" /var/log/sudo.log
```

Comment: You can install rsyslog on the legacy system. Why do you think it exists?

Comment: I don't have enough memory in legacy systems. So, can't install rsyslog. My best bet is to use syslog only.

Comment: Is there any way, I can filter the logs in syslogs? say anything containing ssh or sudo?

Comment: You cannot make syslog do something it is not capable of doing!

Comment: Which syslog implementation? GNU inetutils, syslog-ng,  BSD, something else?

Comment: syslogd (GNU inetutils) 1.5